# function play_game not working when the either of the sum 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 or 10 is tasted

Tags: c

[question found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnYir.jpg)

The function rand_num return sum and if sum is 7 or 11 for the first, it print win and if it either 2, 3 or 12, it print lose for the first roll and that step is working normally.
The problem comes when we have either 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 and 10.if it is either, it print it and request for a new random variable as shown on the program.
    // program simulate the game of craps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 6

// function declation

void play_game (int sum); // function for producing the numbers
int rand_num (void); // function for producing the random dice

// function main

int main ()
{
    int sum;

       // seed random number generaton

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    sum = rand_num();
    play_game (sum);
    return 0;   
 }

 // function for producing the random number of the dice and calculating the sum of the dice

 int rand_num ()
 {
    int sum, dice1, dice2;

    dice1 = 1 + (rand() % SIZE);
    dice2 = 1 + (rand() % SIZE);
    sum = dice1 + dice2;
    return sum;
 }

// function for playing the game craps

void play_game (int sum)
{
    // for the first roll of the dice
    char command;

    do {

// condition for winning for the first roll

    if (sum == 7 || sum == 11){
        printf ("You rolled %d\n", sum);
        printf ("You win!\n");
        printf ("\nPlay again ?  'Y' or 'N'\n");
        scanf ("%c", &command);
    }

// condition for lossing for the first roll 

    else if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12){
        printf ("You rolled %d\n", sum);
        printf ("You loss!\n");
        printf ("Play again ?  'Y' or 'N'\n");
        scanf ("%c", &command);
    }

// condition for winning for the second roll

    else if (sum == 4 || sum == 5 || sum == 6 || sum == 8 || sum == 9 || sum == 10){
        printf ("You rolled %d\n", sum);
        printf ("Your point is %d\n", sum);

        int sum1 = rand_num();           // request new random variable

        while (sum1 != 7 && sum1 != sum){   // 
        printf ("You rolled %d", sum1);

        int sum1 = rand_num ();           // request new random variable

       }
       if (sum1 == 7)
        printf ("You loss!\n");

       else if (sum1 == sum){

        printf ("You win!\n");
        printf ("Play again ?  'Y' or 'N'\n");
        scanf ("%c", &command);
       }
    }
}while (command == 'y' || command == 'Y');

}
```

Comment: How does it taste?

Comment: when it is tested

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the this part of code ;

```
while (sum1 != 7 && sum1 != sum){   // 
        printf ("You rolled %d", sum1);

        int sum1 = rand_num ();           // request new random variable

       }
```

You should use printf when you're sure sum1 will not be 7 and sum1 will not be equal to sum. But in this while loop, there is no exactness. So, you have to use 'if' to check it out.

```
while (sum1 != 7 && sum1 != sum){   //
    if(sum1 != sum || sum1 !=7){
    printf ("You rolled %d", sum1);
    break;
    }
    int sum1 = rand_num ();           // request new random variable

   }
```